# Analyze JAR dependencies in a Java project

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

I'm looking for a tool that will show me a graph of JAR dependencies in my Java project based on static analysis of the compiled byte code. Specifically, I'm trying to figure out if there are unused JARs that I can eliminate, but I'd also just like to get a better understanding of the dependencies that exist. I'm not using Maven.

[Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) comes close, but it deals in packages rather than JARs and there doesn't seem to be any way to query it for JARs that have no dependents. Any recommendations? Free and open source preferred. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/972087/506721

Comment: That question (972087) is Eclipse-specific, although many of the answers are not. I will take a look at JBoss Tattletale, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JBoss Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) does exactly what I need.

Comment: Perfect just what I wanted

Answer (score 8):

See also [JarAnalyzer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer) which claims to:

> ... traverse through a directory, parse
>   each of the jar files in that
>   directory, and identify the
>   dependencies between the jar files.

Comment: I've used this.  It's perfect for what the questioner wants.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on [JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html).

> JDepend traverses Java class file directories and generates design
>   quality metrics for each Java package. JDepend allows you to
>   automatically measure the quality of a design in terms of its
>   extensibility, reusability, and maintainability to manage package
>   dependencies effectively.

Comment: I believe JDepend may not really be useful here. It'll show you only dependencies between packages, not JARs. Hence, if you have the same package in a few JARs they will add some mess to your profile.

Comment: I agree with Przemek.  JDepend is fantastic, but JarAnalyzer is what's needed here.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this tool that displays the public resources of a library and calculates a ratio of usage between two Jars: http://trimatek.org/deep

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com) is a static analysis tool to improve java code quality and it's free for opensource contributors and universities

Answer (score 0):

Or Maven. Elcipse plugin shows it very nicely. Even shows dependencies on the dependencies.

Comment: As I said in my question, this is not a Maven project.