# Check if library will work on a specific verion of Java

Tags: java, maven

What approach can be taken to verify that a library is compatible on a specific version of Java?

Example: Library X was compiled on Java 1.7, therefor it might not work on Java 1.7 or lower.

Thank you.

Comment: By checking the documentation of the library.

Comment: The documentation might be wrong...better check the byte code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best is to check the byte code via an [enforcer rule](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/enforceBytecodeVersion.html) which can be applied to your build by using the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html)...

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-bytecode-version</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <enforceBytecodeVersion>
                  <maxJdkVersion>1.7</maxJdkVersion>
                </enforceBytecodeVersion>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-4</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

compile with the version you want:

```
javac -target ...
```

see that: [How do i compile a .java with support for older versions of java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364761/how-do-i-compile-a-java-with-support-for-older-versions-of-java)

and check jar dependencies: with Jdepend for example

[Analyze JAR dependencies in a Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326407/analyze-jar-dependencies-in-a-java-project)