# jdeps equivalent for Java 7

Tags: java, jdeps

I need to analyse which classes are used (referenced) by the different `.class` files in a jar. I know that

```
jdeps -v example.jar
```

produces this output. Unfortunately, I need a solution that works if the user has only a JDK 1.7. How could this be achieved?

Comment: I guess technically you could do that using `javap -v` or `-c`, but requiring a JDK8 seems like the sane option

Comment: Have a look to the answers in following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326407/analyze-jar-dependencies-in-a-java-project

Comment: @Aaron The users of the program are the developers in our company, which does not use Java 8. I cannot do anything about this.

Comment: @JFMeier I don't think they need to use it, just have an install available so they can run `jdeps`. However I'm not sure `jdeps` can inspect classes from earlier versions. Anyway I guess the question SubOptimal linked should provide you with solutions

Comment: Maybe I can put it on a network drive and call it. It probably does not rely on environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to obtain seemingly good results with `javap -c` and a regex filter.

I used `cygwin` to obtain my results, but you should be able to do this in any environment, all you need is a tool to unzip, `javap` and a tool to execute regular expressions. In current Windows versions, `powershell` would provide those features.

The following code will list the classes referenced by each class inside a jar file :

```sh
mkdir workDir
unzip yourJar.jar -d workDir
shopt -s globstar
for classFile in **/*.class; do
    echo "Classes used in $classFile :"
    javap -c "$classFile" | grep -Eo "([a-zA-Z0-9]+/)+[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" | sort -u
    echo
done
```

You said you wanted the classes referenced in a `jar` file, so assuming you don't want the detail of each class this should work :

```sh
mkdir workDir
unzip yourJar.jar -d workDir
shopt -s globstar
for classFile in **/*.class; do
    javap -c "$classFile" | grep -Eo "([a-zA-Z0-9]+/)+[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" 
done | sort -u
```

Note that this will miss classes which do not follow conventions, for example which are defined in the default package or whose name do not start by a capitalized letter.

You will also retrieve classes which qualified name starts with an `L` : this represents arrays, and you might want to strip that L if you only care about the classname. There are other similar single-letters modifiers I can't remember.

Comment: @JFMeier be careful though, I haven't tested it extensively nor followed the java files specification, I'm pretty sure it must be missing at least some corner cases

Answer (score 1):

Use the JD Java Decompiler (http://jd.benow.ca/).

Comment: I would have definitely looked into that if it were not blocked by our company network as "Streaming Media/MP3" ;-)

Comment: I don't know why that would be the case.  There is a reference to the site from within Wikepedia too.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler .  Perhaps you could ask your network guys to look into it.

Comment: Maybe they'll let you access the github repo:  https://github.com/java-decompiler

Comment: Link to the downloadable .jar file: https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/releases/download/v1.4.0/jd-gui-1.4.0.jar

Comment: I feel like this won't provide more insight than `javap`, maybe I missed a feature? I mean, its output is obviously more human readable, but that doesn't matter if the goal is to programmatically provide a list of referenced classes : you don't want to have to manually parse neither the bytecode nor the source to search for them.

Comment: You can also use the jar as a library for its API (JD-Core) (I haven't tried that). javap is certainly an option if you want to do more than browse the class names.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is put a JDK1.8 on an accessible network drive and call `jdeps` there. This works even when the local JDK is 1.7.