# Find classes which are used during compilation in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have a package x which contains about 30 classes. The program I am compiling uses 5 classes from package x. How to find the 5 classes which are used during my current compilation at a glance?

My current approach is to inspect the code and see which classes are used/instantiated, this is tedious and slow as I have to manually go through the code. Is there a better approach to find all classes which are used during my current compilation?

I want to press a button and see all classes which are required for the compilation of my program.

Answer (score 2):

How about this command:

```
# which jar file you need analyzing
export JAR_FILE="...";
# export CLASSPATH environment for compiling purpose
export CLASSPATH="...";

javac -verbose *.java 2>&1 \
     | grep -E "^\[loading" \
     | grep $JAR_FILE \
     | grep -Eo "\((.*?)\)";
```

### Example

compiling `Main.java`:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      org.joda.time.DateTime dateTime = new org.joda.time.DateTime();
   }
}
```

with commands below:

```
export JAR_FILE="joda-time-2.9.9.jar";
export CLASSPATH="joda-time-2.9.9.jar";
javac -verbose *.java 2>&1 \
     | grep -E "^\[loading" \
     | grep $JAR_FILE \
     | grep -Eo "\((.*?)\)";
```

will outputs the classes that used in `joda.jar` only:

> (org/joda/time/DateTime.class)

Comment: Can it be achieved with an IDE (Eclipse) ?

Comment: @c0der many IDE has code anaylzer plugins too. For eclipse you can find [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/categories/source-code-analyzer).

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I would like to do it out of eclipse (with a plugin if it's not supported out of the box by eclipse), do you have any recommendations for plugins?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta maybe you need extends with [jdeps](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/JDK8/Java+Dependency+Analysis+Tool) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326407/analyze-jar-dependencies-in-a-java-project). you can google to find with "java class usage analyzer lib"  to meet your needs.